# Vue: Can't access Pinia Store in beforeEnter vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, pinia

I am using Vue 3 including the Composition API and additionally Pinia as State Management.

In the options API there is a method beforeRouteEnter, which is built into the component itself. Unfortunately this method does not exist in the composition API. Here the code, which would have been in the beforeRouteEnter method, is written directly into the setup method. However, this means that the component is loaded and displayed first, then the code is executed and, if the check fails, the component is redirected to an error page, for example.

My idea was to make my check directly in the route configuration in the beforeEnter method of a route. However, I don't have access to the Pinia Store, which doesn't seem to be initialized yet, although it is called before in the main.js.

Console Log

```js
Uncaught Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
    const pinia = createPinia()
    app.use(pinia)
This will fail in production.
```

Router.js

```js
import { useProcessStore } from "@/store/process";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
{
    path: "/processes/:id",
    name: "ProcessView",
    component: loadView("ProcessView", "processes/"),
    beforeEnter: () => {
      const processStore = useProcessStore();
      console.log(processStore);
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: "steer",
        name: "ProcessSteer",
        component: loadView("ProcessSteer", "processes/")
      },
      {
        path: "approve/:code",
        name: "ProcessApprove",
        component: loadView("ProcessApprove", "processes/")
      }
    ]
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
});

export default router;
```

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import "@/assets/bundle-bootstrap.css";
import App from "@/App.vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import router from "@/router";
import SvgIcon from "@/components/SvgIcon.vue";

const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(pinia);
app.use(router);
app.component("SvgIcon", SvgIcon);

router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount("#app");
});
```

Comment: I found this one aswell, but this doesn't fit for my case... in here the pinia store is called in router.beforeEach() after the createRouter() .... but i need it only in some routes, and want to call it in beforeEnter of a single route in the routes array, which then is passes as parameter in createRouter() Function

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> However, I don't have access to the Pinia Store, which doesn't seem to be initialized yet, although it is called before in the main.js

Before what? Pinia instance is created with `const pinia = createPinia();` **after** the `router` module is imported - while it is imported, all side-effects including the call to `createRouter()` are executed. Once the router is created it begins it's initial navigation (on client - on server you need to trigger it with `router.push()`) - if you happen to be at URL matching the route with guard that is using Pinia store, the `useProcessStore()` happens before Pinia is created...

[Using a store outside of a component](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html)

You have two options:

- either you make sure that any `useXXXStore()` call happens **after** Pinia is created (`createPinia()`) and installed (`app.use(pinia)`)
- or you pass the Pinia instance into any `useXXXStore()` outside of component...

```js
// store.js
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

const pinia = createPinia();

export default pinia;
```

```js
// router.js
import pinia from "@/store.js";
import { useProcessStore } from "@/store/process";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
{
    path: "/processes/:id",
    name: "ProcessView",
    component: loadView("ProcessView", "processes/"),
    beforeEnter: () => {
      const processStore = useProcessStore(pinia ); // <-- passing Pinia instance directly
      console.log(processStore);
    },
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
});

export default router;
```

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "@/App.vue";
import store from "@/store.js";
import router from "@/router";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(store);
app.use(router);

router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount("#app");
});
```

Comment: I have adapted my code according to your example:

I created a store.js in which the Pinia instance is created, included it in the main.js and in the router.js according to the code examples and passed "Pinia" to the useProcessStore function.

Despite all this, I still get the same error message.

Comment: @Josh Well it works - I'm using it right now in my own app. In fact, it works even without passing Pinia instance into `useStore()` in route guard (initial navigation is triggered always after the app is created - which makes sense because now (as opposed to Router v3) [all navigations are asynchronous](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/index.html#all-navigations-are-now-always-asynchronous). Check that you have no calls to `useStore()` in any file you are importing into `main.js`. Also check that you have latest versions of both Pinia and Router

Comment: I just updated all packages and dependencies, although most were already up to date. I have a component in main.js to use throughout the app which has a call to a Pinia store. However, this makes no difference as the error message also appears when I comment out the component from main.js.

Comment: i just found the problem. in the navigation guard i was calling useXXXStore(pinia) but inside this store i was calling some more stores... i had to pass pinia to those aswell for it to work. thank you very much :)

Comment: This answer saved my day! Thank you!

Comment: Works perfectly, i just needet to remove the createPinia() and .use(pinia) from my main.ts file (I'm using Ionic) as to not create 2 instances.  Wondering if there are any performance drawbacks !?

Answer (score 8):

Hope this would be helpful.
Vue provide support for some functions in which we need store(outside of the components).

To fix this problem I just called the `useStore()` function inside the function provided by Vue(beforeEach) and it worked.

Reference : https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html

Example :

```
import { useAuthStore } from "@/stores/auth";
.
.
.
.
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();

  // use authStore Here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem to access the store in "beforeEach" method for managing authorization.

I use this method in main.js, not in router.js. in router.js store is not accessible.

create pinia instance in piniCreate.js

```
//piniaCreate.js
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
const pinia = createPinia();
export default pinia;
```

after that create my store in mainStore.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
export const mainStore = defineStore('counter', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            user: {
                isAuthenticated: isAuthen,
            }
        }
    },
    actions: {
        login(result) {
            //...
            this.user.isAuthenticated = true;
        }  , 
        logOff() {
            this.user.isAuthenticated = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Then I used beforeEach method in the main.js

```
//main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import pinia from "@/stores/piniaCreate";
import { mainStore } from '@/stores/mainStore';

import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)
    .use(pinia)
    .use(router)
const store1 = mainStore();

router.beforeEach((from) => {
    if (from.meta.requiresAuth && !store1.user.isAuthenticated) {
        router.push({ name: 'login', query: { redirect: from.path } });
    }
})
app.mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the method in the second parameter of definestore:

#### store.js

```js
export const useAppStore = defineStore('app', () => {
  const state = reactive({
    appName: 'App',
    appLogo: ''
  })

  return {
    ...toRefs(state)
  }
})
```

#### router.js

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const apppStore = useAppStore()
  next()
})
```

Answer (score -2):

I have resolved this by adding lazy loading

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  }
]
```