# redirect logged in user if they went to login page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, state-management, pinia

Super beginner here, I just want to know where should I put navigation guards on my app. I have the following code from my **backend/src/main.js**

```
import { createApp, markRaw } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import './axios'
import store from './store'
import router from './router' 
import './index.css'

import App from './App.vue'

const pinia = createPinia();

pinia.use(({ store }) => {
    store.router = markRaw(router);
})
const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)
app.use(pinia)
app.use(store)
app.mount('#app')
```

**backend/src/router/index.js**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Dashboard from '../views/Dashboard.vue'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'
import RequestPassword from '../views/RequestPassword.vue'
import ResetPassword from '../views/ResetPassword.vue'
import Register from '../views/Register.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'dashboard',
    component: Dashboard

  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/forgot-password',
    name: 'requestPassword',
    component: RequestPassword,
  },
  {
    path: '/password-reset/:token',
    name: 'resetPassword',
    component: ResetPassword,
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    component: Register
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: routes,
  linkActiveClass: 'active'
})


export default router
```

and in **backend/src/store/auth.js**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", {
    state: () => ({
        authUser: null,
        authErros: [],
        authStatus: null,
        isLoggedin: false,
    }),
    getters: {
        user: (state) => state.authUser,
        errors: (state) => state.authErros,
        status: (state) => state.authStatus,
        loggedin: (state) => state.isLoggedin,
    },
    actions: {
        async getToken() {
            await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
        },
        async getUser() {
            await this.getToken();
            const data = await axios.get('api/user');
            this.authUser = data.data;
        },
        async handleLogin (data) {
            this.authErros = [];
            await this.getToken();

            try{
                await axios.post('/login', {
                    email: data.email,
                    password: data.password
                });
                this.router.push("/dashboard");
            } catch(error){
                if(error.response.status === 422){
                    this.authErros = error.response.data.errors
                }
            }
        },
        async handleRegister (data)  {
            this.authErros = [];
            await this.getToken();

            try{
                await axios.post('/register', {
                    name: data.name,
                    email: data.email,
                    password: data.password,
                    password_confirmation: data.password_confirmation
                });
                this.router.push("/dashboard");
            } catch(error){
                if(error.response.status === 422) {
                    this.authErros = error.response.data.errors;
                }
            }
        },
        async handleLogout () {
            await axios.post('/logout');
            this.authUser = null;
        },
        async handleForgotPassword (email) {
            this.authErros = [];
            this.getToken();
            try {
                const response = await axios.post('/forgot-password', {
                    email: email
                });
                this.authStatus = response.data.status;
            } catch (error) {
                if(error.response.status === 422) {
                    this.authErros = error.response.data.errors;
                }
            }
        },
        async handleResetPassword (resetData) {
            this.authErros = [];
            try {
                const response = await axios.post('/reset-password', resetData);
                this.authStatus = response.data.status;
            } catch (error) {
                if(error.response.status === 422) {
                    this.authErros = error.response.data.errors;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I have searched everywhere and tried everything. Since I am using pinia not vuex for state management, I cannot get the solution that I want. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I understand correctly, your guard must be implemented in the backend/src/router/index.js file.
You can check the documentation about the router guard here : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html
If you are wondering where you should declare your store in the router file, you can check the pinia documentation talking about it there : https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html#single-page-applications
Hope it can help you ! Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I like to do it is by using a navigation guard in the `Login.vue` itself. This can be done using [In-Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards).

Vue Router provides a navigation guard called `beforeRouteEnter`. It will fire before entering the route.

The idea is that - when the user tries to enter the login page, before entering that page check whether the user is already logged in or not. If yes then abort the routing, else let the routing continue.

It will look something like this:

**Options API:**

```
export default {
  components: {},
  props: {},
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from) {
    // Your code here
  },
  // other component options (like data, methods, etc)
}
```

**Composition API:**

```
export default {
  components: {},
  props: {},
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from) {
    // Your code here
  },
  setup() {
    // other component logic
  }
}
```

> Note: The `beforeRouteUpdate` and `beforeRouteLeave` guards have alternatives for both Options API and Composition API. But I am not sure whether `beforeRouteEnter` has an alternative for Composition API or not.

If you are using the `<script setup>` syntax, then I should mention that there is no support for something like this in `<script setup>` yet ([Reference](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/302)). Instead, you may try a separate ordinary `<script>` block just for using this guard, like this:

```
<script>
  export default {
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from) {
      // Your code here
    },
  }
</script>

<script setup>
   // Component logic here
</script>
```

I see that you are storing the login info in the pinia state. So you can just access that info in the `beforeRouteEnter` and then if the user is logged in then abort the navigation. You can abort navigation by returning `false` from the navigation guard. You can read about it [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards).

Hence the code will be something like:

```
export default {
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from) {
    const isLoggedIn = getLoginStateFromPinia();

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return false;
    }
  },
}
```

If you don't want to use In-Component Guards, then you may want to check out [Per-Route Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard). Per-Route Guards are to be added in your `routes.js` file where you are declaring all your routes. But the catch here is that you need to make sure that the pinia instance is created before the routes are resolved. Otherwise, you will get an error saying that `somePiniaFunction()` was called with no active Pinia instance. I would like to redirect you to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710965/vue-cant-access-pinia-store-in-beforeenter-vue-router) for this purpose.

You can read about the sequence of how these guards are called [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#the-full-navigation-resolution-flow) and choose the one you need.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I learned few things about it. One more question though, because I am still taking a grasp about this one. Based on my code above, how can I use again the navigation guards in redirecting users if they are authenticated or not. Thank you!

Comment: and if you can, can you do it for me? thanks

Comment: If you want to redirect users then you can just return that route location object from the `beforeRouteEnter` guard. it is written in the docs here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards