# Pinia accessed before data is loaded from Api Vue router

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, pinia

I have a **Vue 3** app built with **Pinia** where there are some Api calls on **App.vue** which needs to be run first before the app loads ups and everything thing is dependant on it , one of the api calls is responsible for getting role of current logged in user So I am getting role and setting it in Pinia store which is working great for components however I run into issues when I try to use it in **router.aftereach** event here is the code for

**App.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import { refresh } from './api/user'
import { setAuthToken } from './api'
import { useOrgStore } from '@/stores/organization'
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user'
import { onMounted,ref } from 'vue';
import { getdevices } from '@/api/user'
import { getMembers, getOrganization,getUserMemberships } from '@/api/organization'


const org = useOrgStore()
const user = useUserStore()

let renderApp=ref(false)
onMounted(async() => {
  //refactor for vue 3
  
  //setting user data from vue 2
  let userdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")|| '{}')
  //user data is required for vue 3 to operate if it doesnt exist we redirect user to vue 2 probably the user is logged out
  // and acessing /v3 directly by save url
  if(Object.keys(userdata).length === 0){
    window.location.href = `${window.location.origin}/`
  }
  user.setUser(userdata)
  
  //setting activeBillingAccount from vue 2
  let userBillingInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-active-billing-account")|| '{}')
  user.setActiveBillingAccount(userBillingInfo)

  try{
    if(user.user?.id){
      // devices
      await getdevices(user.user?.id).then(res => {
        user.setDevices(res.data)
      })
    }

    // get organization
    if (user.user?.id) {
      await getUserMemberships(user.user?.id).then(res => {
        org.setUserMembership(res.data)
      });
      
      if(org.userMembership?.length && org.userMembership?.length > 0){
        await getOrganization(org.userMembership?.[0].organizationID ?? '').then(res => {
        org.setOrganization(res.data)
      });
      }
    }
  
    if(org.organization?.id){
      //memberships
      const lastNameAscFilter = 'field=lastName&sort=ASC'
      await getMembers(org?.organization?.id, lastNameAscFilter).then(res => {
        if (res.data.memberships) {
          org.setMembers(res.data.memberships)
        }
      })
    }

  }catch(error){
    console.log("Error on App mounted")
  }
  renderApp.value=true
});

</script>

<template>
  <RouterView v-if="renderApp"/>
</template>
```

The stores are updated as the api calls return their responses and they are async so no problems there, here is the router event

**router.ts**

```
import { useOrgStore } from '@/stores/organization'

router.afterEach((to) => {
  const org = useOrgStore()
  console.log(org.organization) //returns null
})
```

now if do add a timeout it seems to be working meaning it is the data being loaded late from the Api calls which then returns null

```
router.afterEach((to) => {
setTimeout(() => {
  const org = useOrgStore()
  console.log(org.organization) //returns correct value
}, 2000);
})
```

**main.ts**

```
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import i18n from './i18n'
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/vue";


const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(pinia)
app.use(vuetify)
app.use(i18n)
app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

I did try solutions from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710965/vue-cant-access-pinia-store-in-beforeenter-vue-router) but unfortunately it did not work for me ,any help what maybe wrong in my code?

Comment: Your afterEach navigation guard is running before your async operations are done, so it seems as though `v-if` doesn't prevent vue-router code from executing (navigation and rendering are separate things).  I don't think router-view should ever be conditionally rendered, you can use "before" navigation guards for that.  Move your onMounted code into a "before" guard.  It will do the same job of delaying the rendering of the app because you don't confirm the navigation until the async operations are done, and it will also delay any "after" guards as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately After trying alot I could not find a simple enough solution to make it work I had to refactor most of my code to achieve the desired results. I moved my apis calls on from **App.vue** into an action under state then instantiated the store using await on **router.beforeeach** here is the end result

**App.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import { useOrgStore } from '@/stores/organization'
import { watch,ref } from 'vue';

const org = useOrgStore()

let renderApp=ref(false)

//wait for data to be loaded then serve the app
watch(() => org.organization, () => {
  renderApp.value=true
})
</script>

<template>
  <RouterView v-if="renderApp"/>
</template>
```

**auth.ts**

```
actions: {
async loadAuthenticatedUser(){
      const user = useUserStore()
      const org = useOrgStore()
      const userdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")|| '{}')

      if(Object.keys(userdata).length === 0){
        window.location.href = `${window.location.origin}/`
      }
      user.setUser(userdata)
      
      const userBillingInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-active-billing-account")|| '{}')
      user.setActiveBillingAccount(userBillingInfo)

      try{
        if(user.user?.id){
          // devices
          await getdevices(user.user?.id).then(res => {
            user.setDevices(res.data)
          })
        }

        // get organization
        if (user.user?.id) {
          await getUserMemberships(user.user?.id).then(res => {
            org.setUserMembership(res.data)
          });
          
          if(org.userMembership?.length && org.userMembership?.length > 0){
            await getOrganization(org.userMembership?.[0].organizationID ?? '').then(res => {
            org.setOrganization(res.data)
          });
          }
        }
      
        if(org.organization?.id){
          //memberships
          const lastNameAscFilter = 'field=lastName&sort=ASC'
          await getMembers(org?.organization?.id, lastNameAscFilter).then(res => {
            if (res.data.memberships) {
              org.setMembers(res.data.memberships)
            }
          })
        }

      }catch(error){
        console.log("Error on App mounted")
      }
      }
  }
```

**router**

```
router.beforeEach(async (to) => {
  const auth = useAuthStore()
  const org = useOrgStore()
  //load Auth user
  // Todo: Need to move this into login flow for future
  await auth.loadAuthenticatedUser()
  const isOrgOwner =  org.userMembership![0]?.role=="owner"
  if (to.name === 'users-groups' && !isOrgOwner) {
    window.location.replace(`${window.location.origin}/`)
  }
})
```

Even though this was a longer solution than I initially thought but works flawlessly , I hope this help other people stuck at similar situations

Answer (score -1):

Just move router.afterEach from router.ts to app.vue

```js
import router from '@/router'
...
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error on App mounted")
}
renderApp.value = true
router.afterEach((to) => {
  console.log(org.organization) //returns null
})
```